# Buck converter load voltage drop

Tags: power-supply, buck, load, step-down

I'm creating a buck converter from a NE555 and LM358 (feedback loop) for powering a tablet motherboard. (This is a learning experience for me, don't want to use an off-the-shelf board.)

Here is the schematic:

[image]

The simulation on LTSpice works correctly for loads from 1 to 100 Ω.

For a 47 kΩ load the simulation overshoots to around 7 V (the 47 kΩ is what I measure from the tablet).

However, the tablet I'm powering drops the voltage from 5 V to 4.1 V when I hook it up. I tried several inductor capacitances (1 μH to 15 μH) and got the same result.

I'm stuck right now not knowing what to observe or change to make it work.

Comment: If your load is 47k then `R7, R9` will draw more current (and `R11, R12` even more).  There are plenty of other, much better choices for oscillator than the 555. Also, you're using voltage mode, so don't expect good regulation (if it's for a tablet, better re-think your approach, you could damage it). Overshoots can be mitigated by a soft-start.

Comment: 1) Do you really think that your tablet only draws around 0.1mA (47k) when charging? 

2) Are you sure that NFET is turning on properly?

Comment: @Linkyyy 1) No I don't but the voltage sensing is probably done at a very low current so if my circuit cannot work with this low current the tablet won't turn on. 2) Without load or with a 2ohm resistor the output voltage is 5 V so my guess is yes (but I'm not sure).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I know that it is not ideal (other post on stackexchange already exists with a similar design and similar concerns). What do you mean by voltage mode?

Comment: @2A-66-42 I mean the control method. There are voltage mode, current mode, itself with average, peak, cycle-by-cycle, there's hysteresis, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your design:

1. It's quite possible to see much higher voltages across the output during load step changes (e.g. full to half, full to zero, 10% to full, etc.).
2. The way the MOSFET is driven is not good: MOSFET Vgs will be low.
3. The chosen MOSFET is not good for this purpose because the Rds(on) is too high. And this will be even higher because the Vgs will be quite low (the item above). This will increase losses so the MOSFET might overheat then even get broken.
4. There's no overload and short circuit protection mechanism: If the load current increases to a very high value that is enough to break the MOSFET, then the MOSFET will most likely get shorted and the output will be equal to the input voltage (minus some drop).

You can't prevent turn-on overshoot on this design, even a soft start mechanism (such as ramping up ref voltage) won't work. If you analyse the circuit with 555's internals, you'll see that there'll be a few pulses (or maybe a single pulse) at start up, the output capacitor will be charged to a high voltage close to the input, then the switching will stop and will not start until the output decays to 5V again. Remember that the decaying duration depends on the load resistance: The lower it is, the faster the decaying.

The load is a smart device so it may not draw a current until the seen voltage gets within the acceptable limits. But today's quick-charge-supported smart devices accept up to 20VDC so you might be lucky that your device draws current right at start up and not get broken.

> However, the tablet I'm powering drops the voltage from 5 V to 4.1 V when I hook it up.

A few possibilities:

- Your feedback network doesn't work and therefore can't adjust the switching.
- The output capacitor is too low or the ESR is too high. At least one of them makes the output voltage dips deeper. The peaks may hit 5V but the average value will be lower.

Comment: 1. Yes this is what I see in the simulation (The voltage goes up to 90% input before stabilizing depending on the output load)  

2. I'm not sure I understand this point. Do you mean Vgs is 20V and the MOSFET will never be fully open?  

3. Rds(on) is 0.54Ω if I read the datasheet right? (https://www.vishay.com/docs/91015/irf510.pdf). What is the influence of Rds(on) here?  

The load indeed does not draw current until a few parameters are correct (from what I tested)

Comment: @2A-66-42 **2.** The Vgs is the gate-source voltage seen by the MOSFET. The output of the 555 is 15V but the Vgs will be around 5V which is way too low for this MOSFET to be fully on. 20V given in the datasheet is the max allowed Vgs. **3.** Rds(on) is 0.54 "if the Vgs is high enough". In your case the Vgs will be low and therefore the Rds(on) will be high. For the same current, the dissipation of the MOSFET will be higher. This may not affect the output voltage but if the MOSFET gets overheated due to the excessive dissipation it'll get damaged and so will your circuit, and even the load.